# Winsock Connect function is taking too long when Windows firewall is on

Tags: sockets, network-programming, winsock, winsock2, windows-firewall

I have made a client that, when the windows firewall is OFF on the server then it will connect instantly to the server but when the firewall is ON then it takes around 30-35 secs to connect  with server. I have tried adding firewall exceptions on server for my application and for ports as well but nothing is working out, its still taking the same amount of time.

here is my client piece of code where I am trying to connect with server :

```
     bool connectSocket()
    {     

            _connectSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);

            if(_connectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                LOG_ERROR("Failed intiating socket with partner.");
                return false;
            }

            struct sockaddr_in thataddr;

            memset(&thataddr,0,sizeof(thataddr));

            thataddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(_partnerIP.c_str());
            thataddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            thataddr.sin_port = htons(_partnerPort);

            int i = ::connect(_connectSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&thataddr,sizeof(thataddr));

            if(i<0)
            {
                //i = WSAGetLastError();
                LOG_WARNING("Failed connecting to partner. Check partner status.");
                return false;
            }

    }
```

When Firewall is ON on the server ::connect function will take 30-35 secs to give error.
Any help in this direction is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: There's nothing you can do in your client program. But I would recommend using a program such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to check the communication, for example what the server machine send back (if anything) etc.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `connect()` that takes the time, and not the `inet_addr()`?

Comment: @EJP Yes I have Checked its connect function which is taking time.